# NTL Galois Field elements iterate

Tags: ntl

I'm learning NTL and I have a doubt: How will I be able to get any specific element of any finite field?

Here is my code

```
GF2X P = BuildIrred_GF2X(256);
GF2E::init(P);

GF2E zero = GF2E::zero();
GF2E one;
GF2E r = random_GF2E(); //I want change the function random_GF2E()
```

I want change the function `random_GF2E()` by any other to get a specific element.

Answer (score 1):

The Elements of a finite field with 2<sup>256</sup> elements are represented as the polynomials `f` of `deg(f) < 256`.

If you want a special element, you can declare a polynom `p` by something like

```
GF2X p;
p.SetLength(n);
SetCoeff(p,i,1);
```

There is `deg(p) = n`. If `n < deg(P)` (in your case `n < 256`), then this is a special element of the finite field. If `n >= deg(P)` you can reduce it modulo `P` by `conv<GF2E>(p)`.

I hope this is what you were looking for.